# save the output of fix() or page() command to a text file

Tags: r

How can we save the content of fix() or page() to a text file in R?

For example:

```
 hcity.D2 <- hclust(UScitiesD, "ward.D2") # example of hclust in the R help file
```

I want to save the output of `page(hcity.D2)` in to a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use dput() function.

dput(hcity.D2,"test.txt")